# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow - Python

Tags: python, opencv

I went trough many similar topics like mine, but found no solution for my code. First of all I simply want to calibrate my webcam.

This is the code for the capture of the images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ii = 0

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #conv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGR)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif k == ord('s'):
        ii += 1
        cv2.imwrite('framecap{}.png'.format(ii),frame)
        img = cv2.imread('framecap{}.png'.format(ii),1)
        cv2.imshow('frame capture',img)

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is the code for the calibration.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

objpoints = []
imgpoints = []

images = glob.glob('*.png')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7,6), None)

    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11,11), (-1,-1), criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        img2 = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2, ret)

        if not (type(img2) is np.ndarray):
            print 'None'
        else:
            cv2.imshow('img', img2)
            cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I still get this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in cv::imshow (Python)
```

I do not think that this will fix my problem? Has anybody a solution?

Comment: Which of the above two code snippets, raise the error ?

Comment: @JasonSturges the (-1,-1) is a special value used by OpenCV usually to make the function auto-detect something. In this case, [from the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#cornersubpix): "**zeroZone** – Half of the size of the dead region in the middle of the search zone over which the summation in the formula below is not done. It is used sometimes to avoid possible singularities of the autocorrelation matrix. The value of (-1,-1) indicates that there is no such a size."

Comment: Inside of if ret == True, the variable img2 is empty but I do not understand why

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem always occur due to improper use of imread() funtion.
when you will correct the syntex of imread() the error will  gone forever.

Comment: I think you can explain better than this if you got the problem ?